# Why a python pacakge is shown as a module in python 3.5?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am not very familiar with python. I am using `scikit-learn` with python 3.5. This may be a naive question.

In the `site-pacakges\sklearn` folder, I can see a `__init__.py` file. So the `sklearn` should be a **package** according to the [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages). But when I run below code, it says `sklearn` is a **module**.

```
In [21]: sklearn
Out[21]: <module 'sklearn' from '/home/python35/lib/site-packages/sklearn/__init__.py'>
```

Shouldn't it be `package 'sklearn'` instead of `module 'sklearn'`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All Python packages are of type `module`.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-package):

> Technically, a package is a Python module with a `__path__` attribute.

```
>>> import numpy # numpy package
>>> type(numpy)
<type 'module'>
>>> numpy.__path__
['/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/numpy']
>>>
>>> import collections  # collections module
>>> collections.__path__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '__path__'
```

Comment: Thanks. So why doesn't a module have a `__path___` attribute? As I understand, a module is `.py` file and a package is a folder containing several `.py` files among which there's a `__init__.py` file. Since both folder and file have paths, I think both package and module **can** have `__path__` attribute.

Comment: Probably because paths in Python have more to do with directories (packages) than files (modules). Besides, most modules already have a `__file__` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

> Shouldn't it be package 'sklearn' instead of module 'sklearn'?

No. A package contains several modules (like a directory contains several files)